# Adding optional parameters to app insights (Service bus triggered Azure function)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, telemetry

My app consists of service bus triggered azure function, and classic api. I wanted to add 2 optional parameters into App Insights both to API and Azure function. I've already done this for API (I used telemetry initializer), Api was an easy one because there i could inject HttpContext (values of optional parameters are accesible through headers). But now in azure function I can't simply use HttpContext to access these parameters (and use ITelemetry), however they are accesible through helper method used in function. I wonder if there is anyway to add optional parameters to app insights only if this helper method is being used.

Helper function with my first attempt of adding these parameters (not working, doesn't add anything to app insights)

```
public class FunctionHelper 
    {
        private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;
        private static readonly TelemetryConfiguration telemetryConfiguration = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
        private readonly TelemetryClient telemetryClient = new(telemetryConfiguration);

        public FunctionScopeHelper(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }

        public IServiceScope BuildServiceScopeWithContext(string parameter1, string parameter2)
        {
            var requestTelemetry = new RequestTelemetry
            {
                Name = "Function Telemetry"
            };

            var operation = this.telemetryClient.StartOperation(requestTelemetry);

            requestTelemetry.Properties.Add(Parameter1, parameter1);
            requestTelemetry.Properties.Add(Parameter2, parameter2);


            this.telemetryClient.StopOperation(operation);

            // rest of the helper method

            return scope;
        }
    }
```

Second attempt of adding these parameters (still doesn't add anything)

```
public class FunctionHelper 
    {
        private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;
        private static readonly TelemetryConfiguration telemetryConfiguration = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
        private readonly TelemetryClient telemetryClient = new(telemetryConfiguration);

        public FunctionScopeHelper(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }

        public IServiceScope BuildServiceScopeWithContext(string parameter1, string parameter2)
        {
            var requestTelemetry = new RequestTelemetry
            {
                Name = "Function Telemetry"
            };

            var operation = this.telemetryClient.StartOperation(requestTelemetry);

            if (this.telemetryClient.Context.GlobalProperties is ISupportProperties)
            {
                this.telemetryClient.Context.GlobalProperties.Add(Parameter1, parameter1);
                this.telemetryClient.Context.GlobalProperties.Add(Parameter2, parameter2);
            }


            this.telemetryClient.StopOperation(operation);

            // rest of the helper method

            return scope;
        }
    }
```

Here is how I dealed with it on API side (Throught ITelemetryInitializer)

```
    public class TelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAcessor;

        public TelemetryInitializer(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAcessor)
        {
            this.httpContextAcessor = httpContextAcessor;
        }

        public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
        {
            if (telemetry is not ISupportProperties supportPropertiesTelemetry)
            {
                return;
            }

            var httpContext = this.httpContextAcessor.HttpContext;

            if (httpContext != null)
            {
                var (parameter1, parameter2) = HelperClass.GetParameters(httpContext);

                var properties = supportPropertiesTelemetry.Properties;

                if (properties.ContainsKey("Parameter1") || parameter1 == null || parameter2 == null )
                {
                    return;
                }

                properties["Parameter1"] = parameter1;
                properties["Parameter2"] = parameter2;
            }          
        }
    }
```

Hope i explained it well. Thanks for help :)

I tried to add optional parameters with this three aproaches:

1. ITelemetryInitializer (failure: Lack of httpContext in function app)
2. Adding through helper method using RequestTelemetry.Add() (Doesn't add anything to app insights)
3. Adding through helper method using TelemetryClient.Context.GlobalProperties.Add() (Doesn't add anything to app insights as well)

Comment: Did you try to switch to frontend?

Comment: Is it an http triggered azure function?

Comment: Yes it is @PeterBons

Comment: Can you please uodate the question and mention it is a service bus triggered function?

Comment: Can't you just do something like `this.telemetryClient.TrackEvent("ServiceBusMessageProcessed")` and add the properties to the event inside the `FunctionHelper`?

Comment: Yeah, now i used this.telemetryClient.TrackEvent(); (In the functionHelper) and added parameters as i did in the second aproach through Globalproperties and it doesn't added any optional parameters

Answer (score 0):

> To add optional parameters to App Insights in a Service Bus triggered Azure function, you can use the `TelemetryClient.Context.GlobalProperties` property. The `GlobalProperties` property is a dictionary that you can use to store custom properties that are associated with all telemetry items sent by the `TelemetryClient`.

Thanks to `Peter Bons`for the comments.

You can add the optional parameters to the `GlobalProperties` dictionary.

```
public class FunctionHelper
 {

   private readonly TelemetryClient telemetryClient;
   public FunctionHelper()
   {
          this.telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient();
   }
   public void AddOptionalParameters(string parameter1, string parameter2)
   { 
        if (this.telemetryClient.Context.GlobalProperties is ISupportProperties)
           {
                    this.telemetryClient.Context.GlobalProperties.Add("Parameter1", parameter1);
                    this.telemetryClient.Context.GlobalProperties.Add("Parameter2", parameter2);
           }
    }
```

You can then call the `AddOptionalParameters` method in your Azure function and pass in the values of the optional parameters.

The values will be added to the `GlobalProperties` dictionary and will be associated with all telemetry items sent by the `TelemetryClient`.

> If you are unable to add the optional parameters using the `ITelemetryInitializer` or `RequestTelemetry.Add()` method, you can try using the `TelemetryClient.TrackEvent()` method to send custom events to App Insights.

Then you can modify your `FunctionHelper` class to send custom events with the optional parameters.

Sending custom events to App Insights with the `optional parameters`

```
public class FunctionHelper
   {
         private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;
         private static readonly TelemetryConfiguration telemetryConfiguration = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
         private readonly TelemetryClient telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(telemetryConfiguration);

          public FunctionScopeHelper(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
           {
              this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
           }

           public IServiceScope BuildServiceScopeWithContext(string parameter1, string parameter2)
           {
                telemetryClient.TrackEvent("CustomEvent", new Dictionary<string, string>
           {
                { "Parameter1", parameter1 },
                { "Parameter2", parameter2 }
           });

            var serviceScope = serviceProvider.CreateScope();
            return serviceScope;
           }
        }
```

for further information on this, refer to [MSDoc1](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling.md) and [MSDoc2.](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-monitor/app/custom-operations-tracking.md)